# When I try to copy the text from MS Word to Flutter App the format of text is lost

Tags: windows, flutter, dart, textfield

When I copy text from MS word to Flutter App Text field it only copy simple text the format of text is not copy or can not see into the Flutter Text field. Any body have any idea how to solve this.

I have fid the package related to this but can not find any thing for Flutter Windows